# Android SQLite NOT LIKE syntax

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, android-studio, syntax

I want to select name from database, that does not match the name, who already exists.
Using this code, throws error: `No such table`

```
public String getRandomAnswer(String correctName){
     String randomAnswer;
     mDbHelper.initializeDataBase();
     try {
         mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
         String sql = "SELECT Name FROM Cities WHERE Name NOT LIKE " + correctName + " ORDER BY Random() LIMIT 1 ";
         Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
         if (c != null) {
             if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                 randomAnswer = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name"));
                 return randomAnswer;
             }
             c.close();
         }
     } catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
     } finally {
         try {
             mDbHelper.close();
         } catch (Exception ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
         } finally {
             mDb.close();
         }
     }
     return null;
 }
```

But if I put word directly `String sql = "SELECT Name FROM Cities WHERE Name NOT LIKE 'someOtherName' ORDER BY Random() LIMIT 1 ";`
Than its works, but it's not, what I want.

Comment: Use parameters instead of string concatenation for the value in your query.

Comment: @stickybit If I understand correctly: `Cursor c = mDb.query("Cities", new String[] {"Name"},"Name NOT LIKE ?", new String[]{correctName}, null, null, "Random()", String.valueOf(1));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider SQL parameterization instead of string concatenation since you need to enclose your variable in single quotes. Otherwise, the engine assumes you refer to a column or table identifier. The method [**`rawQuery`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) supports parameters. Additionally, `LIKE` without wildcards should use equality instead, `=`. But if needing wildcards, append to parameter.

```
// PREPARED STATEMENT WITH QMARKS, ?
String sql = "SELECT Name FROM Cities WHERE Name NOT LIKE ? ORDER BY Random() LIMIT 1 ";

// QUERY EXECUTION WITH BINDED VALUE AND WILDCARDS
Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{ "%"+correctName+"%" });
```